# JQuery not displaying hidden DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTable in a bootstrap modal.
I have wrapped datatable around in a `div` which has css of `display: none` initially.
Once the modal window loads I am trying to make the datatable visible based on the value of a field in modal.

I have written code to show/hide div in a function and I am invoking that function on `shown.bs.modal` event of modal.
The function gets called and code to display div gets executed but div is still hidden.
I have tried number of various ways to make div visible but it wouldn't budge and remain hidden.
I tried calling `show` as well as `css('display','block')`

Relevant HTML code is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userTable" style="display:none">
  <table id="users" class="display compact nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
</div>
```

Javascript code is:

```js
function showHideUsers() {
   $('#userTable').show();
   $('#userTable').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: Just to check... have you tried it with content in the table?

Comment: Can you confirm that inside of the `shown.bs.modal` that your function is being called? Just place an `alert` in there or use the browser debugger.

Comment: downvoting should include some explanation...

Comment: @Canvas Yes, the function is getting called. I have already ensured it by adding alert as well as console.log. And there is plenty of data in the table. I have posted only relevant HTML code to keep it concise.

Comment: Check Style "Display:none" Opacity:0 and ... in browser html inspector and check some properties...

Comment: Use jQuery Event's inside `$(document).ready(function(){ .... });`

Comment: Yes, all JS code is inside $( document ).ready(function() {});

Comment: Can you confirm that there is only one element with id `userTable`, and that the table appears when you remove the `display:none` style?

Comment: @Owlvark Yes, there is only one div with that Id and table appears fine if I remove 'display:none'. The div that I need to hide/show is in bootstrap modal dialog. And modal dialog is loaded dynamically by making a call to server using href attribute. As mentioned, div is hidden by default and when modal shows up I am trying to show the div inside shown.bs.modal' event. It doesn't work. Once modal loads I am triggering same hide/show actions on change event of a dropdown which works perfectly. So my guess is that DOM elements (div) are not ready yet when i use them inside 'shown.bs.modal'.